# Restrict su to domain user in Winbind/Kerberos Linux AD integration

Tags: linux, su, winbind

We've got some RHEL 5 servers joined to AD using Winbind/Kerberos which is working well overall.

I've specified an AD security group in PAM to restrict which domain users can login.

```
auth        requisite     pam_succeed_if.so user ingroup ad_group debug
```

I've also specified the same group in sudoers so they can attain root access.

```
%ad_group ALL=(ALL)     ALL
```

These work as expected.

However, I've noticed that "su -" will allow me to become a domain user that is not in the security group.

Let's say jdoe is not in the "ad_group":

```
[kernelpanic@server01 ~]$ sudo su - jdoe
[sudo] password for user:
Creating directory '/home/jdoe'.
Creating directory '/home/jdoe/.mozilla'.
Creating directory '/home/jdoe/.mozilla/plugins'.
Creating directory '/home/jdoe/.mozilla/extensions'.
[jdoe@server01 ~]$
```

Here's the /var/log/secure output:

```
Oct 25 09:42:42 server01 su: pam_unix(su-l:session): session opened for user jdoe by kernelpanic(uid=0)
Oct 25 09:43:53 server01 su: pam_unix(su-l:session): session closed for user jdoe
```

Is there a way to restrict users from an "su -" to a domain user who is not allowed to login to the box in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the first line in `/etc/pam.d/su` looks like this:

```
auth            sufficient      pam_rootok.so
```

In other words, when you su tries to authorize your to become jdoe, everything looks okay.

What you can do is either add your `pam_succeed_if` line to `/etc/pam.d/su`, or much better, add an entry to `/etc/pam.d/system-auth`, but modify it so the `auth` becomes `session` like so:

```
session requisite pam_succeed_if.so user ingroup ad_group debug
```

This will get triggered even in the situation that you described and will not let a user from the non ad_group to ever open a shell. This would also have the unfortunate side effect of restricting `root` from opening a shell (as pointed out in the comments), so you may need to only apply it for user ids in the correct range:

```
session [default=1 success=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so quiet uid >= 1000
session requisite pam_succeed_if.so user ingroup ad_group debug
```

By the way, `ssh` may also bypass PAM if you are authenticating with a public key, so it is still better to use `session` instead of `auth`.

Comment: I replaced auth with session for that line in system-auth but it caused "sudo su -" to break.

Comment: Fair point. I updated my answer to accommodate for this.